# Is there an extension like "It's all text!" for Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer-9, ie-extensions

I have to do some CMS integration work using Interwoven TeamSite, but the only supported browser for the admin interface is Internet Explorer and I would prefer to use an external editor. Is there an extension or add-on for Internet Explorer that will let me open textareas in an external editor?